# How to find the complex primitive/antiderivative explicitly?

Tags: complex-analysis

So for my complex analysis class, I have to find the antiderivatives of a few functions - namely $e^{cz}$, for a fixed $c=ib$, and $\frac{1}{z}$ (the latter with the domain being the complex plane, with nonponsitive reals deleted).

Intuitively, I get the idea of an antiderivative; a function $F(z)$ would be an antiderivative of $f(z)$ if $F'(z) = f(z)$. So the obvious answers would be $\frac{1}{ib}e^{ibz}$ and $ln(z)$, respectively and up to a constant $C$, at least I think.

Regardless, what the professor told us to do was to use some sort of "integrating method" mentioned in the textbook. (A picture of pretty much the entirety of the section we were directed to - https://i.imgtc.com/gykYsfF.png)

My issue being that the book doesn't seem to give *any* sort of "method" at all, and at the end of the section seems to pull that primitive out of thin air (disregarding that we generally already would assume that $\int dx/x = ln|x|+C$ from ordinary calculus).

My question being - am I overlooking something obvious in the section that would give this underlying "method"? How would one normally find the antiderivative/primitive under normal circumstances?

For what it's worth we also given a few formulas to use for the $e^{cz}$ problem:

$$\int e^{ax} \cdot sin(bx)dx = \frac{e^{ax}}{a^2 + b^2}(a \cdot sin(bx) - b \cdot cos(bx))+ C$$
$$\int e^{ax} \cdot cos(bx)dx = \frac{e^{ax}}{a^2 + b^2}(a \cdot cos(bx) + b \cdot sin(bx))+ C$$

I'm sorry if this seems dumb, I'm just completely lost and me Googling and searching on here got me nothing at all. It seems dumb that I can intuitively guess (even if I'm in error, which I guess I probably am) the antiderivative without being able to properly justify that answer. Any nudge in the right direction would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, this was explained to me in more detail in a mass email by my professor - it boiled down to vagueness in what he meant by "method."

Essentially we fix some $z_0$ and integrate to some arbitrary $z$. That is the "method," in the end, nothing more, aside from a convenient $z_0$ and choices of contours.

At least it makes sense now.

Answer (score 0):

Of course $\int e^{cz}\; dz = e^{cz}/c + C$, just as in calculus.
$\int \frac{dz}{z} = \log(z) + C$, but you have to be careful
with what this means: how do you define the logarithm of a complex number?  This is an example of a **multivalued function**, but you probably haven't got that far in your text yet. On the complex plane with the nonpositive reals deleted, you can define it as follows: if $z = r e^{i\theta}$ is the polar representation of $z$, with $r > 0$ and $-\pi < \theta < \pi$, then $\log(z) = \ln(r) + i \theta$.  This is what's called the **principal branch** of the logarithm.

Comment: My question moreso lies in how am I supposed to actually determine the antiderivative - not that your answer isn't helpful in understanding at least where the primitive on the second page of the linked picture comes from. But I'm more concerned with justifying actually obtaining the primitive. The absolute closest thing to a method I can possibly grasp from the text is just to have $F(z) = \int_{z_0}^z e^{cz} dz + C$ and calculate the integral. Which I did, but that gave me $C - i/b [e^{ibz} - e^{ibz_0}]$ (and differentiating yielded the bracketed expression, i.e. $f(z)-f(z_0)$, not $f(z)$.)

Comment: Or rather, just to clarify as much as I can - I'm less concerned with the actual primitive, as the method to find it.

Comment: You can always check an antiderivative by differentiating, so any method that works is OK.  In general, all the methods of elementary calculus work for complex functions as well - the one caveat being that you want to use $\log(z)$ rather than $\ln(|z|)$ for the antiderivative of $1/z$.  That absolute value was just a kludge to avoid logarithms of negative numbers, and you don't want it here because $|z|$ is not analytic.